# Automatically run 'mvn verify'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I successfully setup java + cucumber test automation. At the moment I try to setup *.html report. I use cucumber-maven-report([link](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting)) 
The problem is:
 after each test execution I need to run in terminal mvn verify, to update *.html report. If there is possibilities to run mvn verify automatically after each execution? I use intellij. Thank you!

Comment: Do you run your tests from within intellij?

Comment: In any case running mvn verify should also run your tests, if that's configured in your pom.

Comment: I also can run tests from terminal .But for me will be better to run tests from intellij.

Comment: And there is part of pom.
<phase>verify</phase>

 <goal>generate</goal>

Comment: You can create a run configuration to run maven from intellij.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set maven goals to be executed automatically](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html) after certain events or create a [Compound run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-compound.html) that will consist of 2 configurations (run tests, [run maven verify](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-maven.html)).